# Guardar todos los valores obtenidos desde simplexml

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo un detalle al intentar guardar todos los valores obtenidos desde un xml (una factura)

El codigo va algo asi:
Recibo los datos de simplexml que mando por medio de un post.

```
$filex = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$ID = $_POST['numero_factura'];
$numero_factura_u = $ID;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filex); 
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('cfdi', $ns['cfdi']);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('t', $ns['tfd']);
```

Esmpiezo a asiganr variables a todos los datos de la factura obtenidos.

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Emisor') as $Emisor){
    $emisor=$Emisor['Rfc'];  
    $emisor_nombre=$Emisor['Nombre'];
    } 
foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Emisor//cfdi:DomicilioFiscal') as $DomicilioFiscal){ 
    $emisor_pais=$DomicilioFiscal['Pais']; 
    $emisor_calle=$DomicilioFiscal['Calle']; 
    $emisor_estado=$DomicilioFiscal['Estado']; 
    $emisor_colonia=$DomicilioFiscal['Colonia']; 
    $emisor_municipio=$DomicilioFiscal['Municipio']; 
    $emisor_noexterior=$DomicilioFiscal['NoExterior']; 
    $emisor_codigopostal=$DomicilioFiscal['CodigoPostal'];
    }
foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Receptor') as $Receptor){
    $receptor=$Receptor['Rfc'];
    $receptor_nombre=$Receptor['Nombre'];
    }

foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Conceptos//cfdi:Concepto') as $Concepto){ 
    $concepto_unidad=$Concepto['Unidad']; 
    $concepto_importe=$Concepto['Importe']; 
    $concepto_cantidad=$Concepto['Cantidad']; 
    $concepto_descripcion=$Concepto['Descripcion']; 
    $concepto_valorunitario=$Concepto['ValorUnitario'];
    }     
foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Impuestos//cfdi:Traslados//cfdi:Traslado') as $Traslado){ 
    $traslado_tasa=$Traslado['Tasa'];
    $traslado_importe=$Traslado['Importe'];
    $traslado_impuesto=$Traslado['Impuesto']; 
    }
foreach ($xml->xpath('//t:TimbreFiscalDigital') as $tfd) {
    $tfd_sellocfd=$tfd['SelloCFD']; 
    $tfd_fechatimbrado=$tfd['FechaTimbrado']; 
    $uuid=$tfd['UUID']; 
    $tfd_nocertificadoSAT=$tfd['NoCertificadoSAT']; 
    $tfd_Version=$tfd['Version']; 
    $tfd_SelloSAT=$tfd['SelloSAT'];
    }
```

Posteriormente realizo una consulta para insertar los datos en una base de datos:

```
$insertxml=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO 
            xml (
            id_oc, 
            cfdi_version, 
            cfdi_fecha, 
            cfdi_sello, 
            emisor, 
            emisor_nombre,
            concepto_unidad, 
            concepto_importe, 
            concepto_cantidad, 
            concepto_descripcion, 
            concepto_valorunitario
            )

            VALUES (
            '$numero_factura_u', 
            '$cfdi_version', 
            '$cfdi_fecha', 
            '$cfdi_sello', 
            '$emisor', 
            '$emisor_nombre',
            '$concepto_unidad', 
            '$concepto_importe', 
            '$concepto_cantidad', 
            '$concepto_descripcion',
            '$concepto_valorunitario'
            );");
```

El problema es que al guardar la base de datos solo me guarda el primer registro, la factura tienen varios productos y estoy intentando que por cada linea de producto guarde una linea con toda la informacion por cada producto en la factura.

pero estoy algo perdido en el tema.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Tendrías que ejecutar `mysqli_query` dentro de un bucle para que se ejecute  `N` veces, según la cantidad de filas a ingresar. Esa es la forma más simple, pero no la mejor. Para estos casos es mejor usar transacciones y también consultas preparadas. Así preparas la consulta una sola vez y luego ejecutas para insertar los distintos valores. Ganas en rendimiento y además, proteges tu entorno contra ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, yo automatizaría los valores que se extraen del XML:

```php
$grupos = [
  [
    'grupo' => 'emisor',
    'xpath' => '//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Emisor',
    'campos' = ['Rfc', 'Nombre'],
  ],
  [
    'grupo' => 'emisor',
    'xpath' => '//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Emisor//cfdi:DomicilioFiscal',
    'campos' = ['Pais', 'Calle', 'Estado', 'Colonia', 'Municipio', 'NoExterior', 'CodigoPostal'],
  ],
  // y así...
];
$datos = [];
foreach ($grupos as $grupo) {
  foreach ($xml->xpath($grupo['xpath']) as $index => $xmldata) {
    // aquí creo que es donde no consigues extraer varias entradas
    // pero no estoy seguro
    if ( !isset($datos[$index]) ) {
      $datos[$index] = [];
    }
    foreach ($grupo['campos'] as $campo) {
      $datos[$index][$grupo['grupo'] . '_' . strtolower($campo)] = $xmldata[$campo];  
    }
  }
}
```

Luego, ya puedes hacer varios inserts:

```php
$campos = '(id_oc, cfdi_version, cfdi_fecha, cfdi_sello, emisor, emisor_nombre, concepto_unidad, concepto_importe, concepto_cantidad, concepto_descripcion, concepto_valorunitario)';
$valores = '(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'; // 11 valores

foreach ($datos as $elemento) {
  $insertxml = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO xml $campos VALUES $valores");
  $insertxml->bind_param("si",
    $numero_factura_u,
    $cfdi_version, // estos tres cfdi_* no se dabe de dónde salen
    $cfdi_fecha, 
    $cfdi_sello, 
    $elemento['emisor_rfc'],
    $elemento['emisor_nombre'],
    $elemento['concepto_unidad'], 
    $elemento['concepto_importe'], 
    $elemento['concepto_cantidad'], 
    $elemento['concepto_descripcion'],
    $elemento['concepto_valorunitario']
  );
  $insertxml->execute();
  $insertxml->close();
}
```